# C# Multi Spintax - Spin Text

Tags: c#, spintax

I got this class that I'm using for spin text.

```
    public class Spinner
    {
        private static Random rnd = new Random();
        public static string Spin(string str)
        {
            string regex = @"\{(.*?)\}";
            return Regex.Replace(str, regex, new MatchEvaluator(WordScrambler));
        }
        public static string WordScrambler(Match match)
        {
            string[] items = match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 2).Split('|');
            return items[rnd.Next(items.Length)];
        }
    }
```

But I need it to be able to spin multi spintax text.

As example
{1|2} - {3|4}

Returns: 2 - 4
So it works.

But:
{{1|2}|{3|4}} - {{5|6}|{7|8}}

Returns: 2|4} - {5|7}

So it doesn't work if there is spintax inside spintax.

Any help? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spintax C# ... How can I handle this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004465/spintax-c-sharp-how-can-i-handle-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not good in [dealing with nested structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets), which means you should probably try a different approach.

In your example, `{{1|2}|{3|4}} - {{5|6}|{7|8}}` is the same as `{1|2|3|4} - {5|6|7|8}`, so maybe you don't need nested spintax.

Comment: Isn't this a comment?

Comment: Yeah, should have been, sorry...

Comment: Or make it an answer... Thanks.